# Finding the inverse of an operator (in closed form)

Tags: functional-analysis, inverse

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a function in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, with $1\leq p\leq \infty$. For $a\in \mathbb{R}$, define the translation operator $\tau_a$ by $\tau_a f(x)=f(x-a)$.

Let 
$$
Tf =f+i\frac{\tau_a f -\tau_{-a}f}{2},
$$
where $i^2=-1$. Clearly $T$ is a bounded linear operator in $L^p$ (in fact, it should be in any rearrangement invariant space).

The question is the following: Does $T$ possess an inverse, and if the answer is positive, is there a closed form for $T^{-1}$? I have tried finding such an inverse explicitly by considering 
$$
T^{-1}f=f+i \frac{\pm \tau_a f \pm\tau_{-a}f}{2}
$$
without any success.

Comment: hint: try Fourier transforming

Comment: $Tf=g$, solve for $f$.  This is a difference equation of order 2 with constant coefficients.  The homogeneous equation $Tf=0$ of course has an explicit closed-form solution space of dimension 2.  You could try variation of parameters to get a particular solution for the inhomogeneous equestion $Tf=g$. I haven't tried it yet, but I suspect the solution is not what you call "closed form".